# App to check computer spec?

Tags: hardware

Say I want to know what my motherboard, CPU, graphic card and stuff in one specific app.

I think I saw one already.

What should I have done?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are three ways to go:

1. a visualizer of your hardware, which shows their status, like OpenHardwareMonitor
2. a performance test, like userbenchmark or passmark
3. or something grabbing only details like CPU-Z